# How to access private method in spec file (Karma - Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to access private members in spec file for unit test case.

Here is my sample code

```
private firstMessage = MessageInterface
private firstName = any

public namecalling(): void{
this.firstMessage = undefined;
this.firstName = undefined
}
```

Here is what I am trying to spec file code - Karma I have already imported service file in the spec file and I am trying to access the same

```
it('should call namecalling', () =>{
namesfc.namecalling();
expect(namesfc.firstMessage).toBeUndefined;
expect(namesfc.firstName).toBeUndefined;
}
```

I was trying like above code but I'm getting error on firstMessage here is the error (property firstMessage is private and only accessible within class 'namesfc').

Do I need to set using spyon on set or get to access private method?

Comment: I tried that also but not able to access private method

Comment: You shouldn't be testing private methods in unit tests.

Comment: This is just TypeScript. Cast object to `any` then you can access private props without error. But.. you shouldn't test private members and functions. Unit tests should test only public interface.